# Date Picker Style different in different app in android

Tags: android

date picker dialog shows different style in different app..
What is solution for that??
i am use same code for both app...

```
 final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();

    DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener dob = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker v, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

            calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
            calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);

        }};

    DatePickerDialog dialog = new DatePickerDialog(AddTask.this, dob, calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR),
            calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    dialog.getDatePicker().setMinDate(new Date().getTime());
    dialog.show();
```

[image: date picker dialog shows different style in different app..]

Comment: Could you post your code?

Comment: @DimaKozhevin here i update code in question..